# Why is my PrimeNG Tabindex not working in Dialog

Tags: angular, primeng, tabindex

Currently my tabindex is not working in a primeng dialog.
Does anyone know what's wrong?
You can see an example over here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dialog-captive-tab-2-model-kmsajd?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: What do u want to do with tabindex? U are not using it. What do y want when ı open modal?

Comment: Welcome, @Jeroen on StackOverflow, It would be really helpful to others if you attached your code with your question. So they can help you to rectify your error. for more details please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you manage to find a solution maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Set dialog's focusTrap attribute to false in order to use tabindex:

```
<p-dialog [focusTrap]="false">
    <input tabindex="1" type="text">
    <input tabindex="3" type="text">
    <input tabindex="2" type="text">
    <input tabindex="4" type="text">
    <input tabindex="6" type="text">
    <input tabindex="5" type="text">
</p-dialog>
```